# html line wrap <li><span></span><span></span></li>

Tags: html, css

With the following code below I thought that the text would wrap within its  container, but the text wraps to the beginning of the line.

How do I get the text to wrap within its own container?

Thank you

```css
.recsubsection {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /*text-shadow: 1px 1px #0000FF;*/
}

.recquantity {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.recdescript {
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<li class="recsubsection">
  <span class="recquantity">1 Kg</span>
  <span class="recdescript">
        Apples, 2/3 Spies, 1/3 Empires, peeled, cut into 1 cm pieces, 
        lightly Salted, add 1 Lime Juice, mix well, cover, set aside for 1 hour
   </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not just list words and markup. See [ask]. Also, text wraps by default. You'll need to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` are not containers, they are tags to apply styles to text inline, they do not create a new DOM element. You need to use elements that do function as containers or style your elements to behave in that way.

Here, I changed your `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags, and applied flexbox to the `<li>` to get the flow you wanted.

```css
.recsubsection {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.recquantity {
  width: 20%;
}

.recdescript {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<li class="recsubsection">
  <div class="recquantity">1 Kg</div>
  <div class="recdescript">
        Apples, 2/3 Spies, 1/3 Empires, peeled, cut into 1 cm pieces, 
        lightly Salted, add 1 Lime Juice, mix well, cover, set aside for 1 hour
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @CountryRabbit If this answered your question, please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use flex-box and add the next line to recsubsection selector in your CSS code:

`display: flex;`

This way you wrap each span within its own container.
(You should also change your HTML code and use more semantically meaningful tags)

Answer (score 1):

Instead `float` try [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
.recsubsection { display: flex; font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px; }
.recquantity { width: 25%;}
```

```html
<li class="recsubsection">
   <span class="recquantity">1 Kg</span>
   <span class="recdescript">
        Apples, 2/3 Spies, 1/3 Empires, peeled, cut into 1 cm pieces, 
        lightly Salted, add 1 Lime Juice, mix well, cover, set aside for 1 hour
   </span> 
</li>
```